# MySQL: How to SELECT FROM a custom set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a given list of patient IDs which I want to interact in, something like this:

> SELECT * FROM (LIST OF IDs) WHERE ....

is it possible to have something similar to this using mysql?

Comment: This is possible. ```.. FROM (SELECT 1 AS `id` UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 ..) AS `list_of_ids` WHERE ..```. If ids list can be generated by some arithmetic expression then you may generate it in CTE.

Comment: I guess this will work but I'm dealing with unknown number of ids, but everywhere I read I just find this approach.. I thought i could find something like in the example `... FROM (1,2,3,5,8,9...) WHERE ...`

Answer (score 0):

it is feasible using IN in WHERE section

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <field> IN (<your list of ids comma separated>)
```

Note that this is valid up to 10 ids. With more the performance of the query will definitively decline and there are different approaches (temporary tables to join). But in that case I'd review your database schema to see if this is the correct approach

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend to use a subquery in `WHERE id IN (...)`, just like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM table1
             WHERE conditions... )
```

With this, you can add more conditions in both WHERE's and performance will be fine.

Comment: performance won't be fine if you evaluate more than 10 ids in in even if retrieved by a subquery.